# KeyError: 'tickets' Json API with Python

Tags: python, json, zendesk-api

I had created App to exporting excel file from Zendisk to help my to Analysis data
But yesterday stop working with this error

```
line 20, in <module>
    tickets = page_data['tickets'] # extract the "tickets" list from the page
KeyError: 'tickets'
```

I know this error mean key tickets not found in JSON file but actually there are tickets in file

Code:

```
print(f'Getting tickets from view ID {view_id}')
url = f'https://****.zendesk.com/api/v2/views/{view_id}/tickets.json'
while url:
   response = requests.get(url, auth=auth)
   page_data = response.json()
   tickets = page_data['tickets']     # ERROR here
   view_tickets.extend(tickets)
   url = page_data['next_page']
```

JSON Page

```
{
  "tickets": [
    {
      "url": "https://****.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/55251281.json",
      "id": *******,
      "external_id": null,
      "via": {
        "channel": "api",
        "source": {
          "from": {},
          "to": {},
          "rel": null
        }
      },
```

Comment: Is that the exact JSON which caused this error or an example one that's usually returned by the API? It doesn't seem possible with the JSON you gave.

Comment: One suggestion is to first check the error code from the response. Maybe the Zendesk API returns different data if it hits a 500 error.

Comment: Hi when i typing https://****.zendesk.com/api/v2/views/{view_id}/tickets.json in browser i got above JSON Code and i have working on it to get code works and it works normal till yesterday

Answer (score 1):

Current code:

```
...
   response = requests.get(url, auth=auth)
   page_data = response.json()
   tickets = page_data['tickets']     # ERROR here
...
```

Required code in order to find the problem:

(The code below will catch 2 situations. **1)** HTTP GET failed **2)** No 'tickets' in the response )

```
...
   response = requests.get(url, auth=auth)
   if response.status_code == 200:
     page_data = response.json()
     print(page_data) 
     if 'tickets' in page_data:
       tickets = page_data['tickets']  
     else:
       print(f'no tickets in the response (url: {url})') 
   else:
     print(f'HTTP GET (url: {url}) failed with status code {response.status_code}') 
...
```

Comment: line 28, in <module>
    view_tickets.extend(tickets)
NameError: name 'tickets' is not defined
 i got same error thats mean HTTP request is correct right ?

Comment: Yes. I think so.

Comment: So how can i fix it :(

Comment: What is the payload that you get from the server in the case there are no tickets? See if the Zendesk docs touches this situation.

Comment: no there are tickets i can open in Chrome i got JSON file normal